# How can I loop the video when I left click on it?

Tags: c#, loops, video, unity-game-engine, movie

Here's the code I'm using :

```
[RequireComponent (typeof(AudioSource))]
public class video : MonoBehaviour {

    public MovieTexture movie;
    public bool loop;
    private AudioSource audio;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        GetComponent<RawImage> ().texture = movie as MovieTexture;
        audio = GetComponent<AudioSource> ();
        audio.clip = movie.audioClip;
        movie.Play ();enter code here
        audio.Play ();
        movie.loop = true ();

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
    }

    void onMouseDown (){

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0)&& !movie.isPlaying)
            movie.Play ();
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.mouse) && movie.isPlaying)
            movie.Pause ();
    }
}
```

What I want is when I click the video, the video plays, finishes, and if I click the video again, it restarts the video.

Comment: It's no good just dumping your code! Please explain more in detail; what you want to do, what errors you get, etc! :)

Comment: I'm using rawImage as a movie texture(as you can see in my coding) in a scene, the video started to play when i'm in that scene but then stopped. What I want is to do is to replay the current video by left clicking the mouse button.

Comment: So, click to start playing and then the video keeps playing over and over again, or the video plays, finishes, and then restarts when you click the video?

Comment: yeah what I want is when i click the video, the video play, finished, and if I click the video again, it restart the video.

Answer (score 0):

```
movie.loop = true;
```

Just Google next time: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MovieTexture-loop.html

Comment: if i did that, it keeps loop and never stop. I want to when I click the video, the video replay by clicking the left button mouse.

Answer (score 0):

I think what is needed is a check to see if the movie is finished playing or not.

I've not done any work with movies in Unity, so this is hypothetical, but something like this might work:

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0) && movie.hasFinishedPlaying)
{
    movie.Play ();
}
```

What this sort of pseudocode is saying is that, if the movie has finished, and we click the mouse down, then we play the movie again.

I've just glanced at your code again. What you seem to be doing is doing a pause method in the `OnMouseDown` function, and setting the `movie.loop` to true.

However, setting something to true should be like this:

```
movie.loop = true;
```

And **not** like this:

```
movie.loop = true();
```

Unless it is different for using movies in Unity, but I don't know :) Give it a try!

Comment: Thankyou for helping but,   


if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0) && movie.hasFinishedPlaying)
{
    movie.Play ();
}

can't be used

Comment: Like I said in my answer, .hasFinishedPlaying is a pseudocode variable that I used to get an idea down - it's not an actual variable!

I strongly recommend you have a look at this article: http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-MovieTexture.html

It contains a lot of useful information about using `MovieTexture` as well as some code examples. In fact what I think you're looking for is in one of the code examples.

Comment: Ah I'm really bad at coding, so I can't really figure it out by my self. Well I give it a try then. Thanks again. :')

Comment: Help, I finally figure it out, but It's not when i'm clicking on the rawImage, its replay when I click anything on the screen. How do I fix this?

Comment: Either edit your existing question, or close this one and post a new one.